# TQDM progress bar stuck at zero , and there is no change

Tags: python, epoch, yolov5, tqdm

Trying to train epochs but there is no change .

EPOCH 1 of 10
Training...
0%|          | 0/563 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

waited for 20mins and there was no change in the progress bar

```
# The training function always returns a list containing the training loss values
# for all the completed iterations

# function for running training iterations
def train(train_data_loader, model):
    print('Training...')
    global train_itr
    global train_loss_list
    
     # initialize tqdm progress bar
    prog_bar = tqdm(train_data_loader, total=len(train_data_loader))
    
    for i, data in enumerate(prog_bar):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        images, targets = data
        
        images = list(image.to(DEVICE) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(DEVICE) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
        loss_dict = model(images, targets)
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        loss_value = losses.item()
        train_loss_list.append(loss_value)
        train_loss_hist.send(loss_value)
        losses.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_itr += 1
    
        # update the loss value beside the progress bar for each iteration
        prog_bar.set_description(desc=f"Loss: {loss_value:.4f}")
    return train_loss_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `update` and `refresh` method

```py
def train(train_data_loader, model):
    print('Training...')
    global train_itr
    global train_loss_list
    
     # initialize tqdm progress bar
    prog_bar = tqdm(train_data_loader, total=len(train_data_loader))
    
    for i, data in enumerate(prog_bar):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        images, targets = data
        
        images = list(image.to(DEVICE) for image in images)
        targets = [{k: v.to(DEVICE) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
        loss_dict = model(images, targets)
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        loss_value = losses.item()
        train_loss_list.append(loss_value)
        train_loss_hist.send(loss_value)
        losses.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_itr += 1
    
        # update the loss value beside the progress bar for each iteration
        prog_bar.set_description(desc=f"Loss: {loss_value:.4f}")
        # Add these
        prog_bar.update()
        prog_bar.refresh()

    prog_bar.close()
    return train_loss_list
```